# How to get log message of a merged revision

Tags: svn, terminal

Lets say I have checked out a branch. And in the last commit I have the message:

> "Cherry picked r124 from trunk"

What is the easiest way to check the trunk `r124` log message so that I get an idea what it is fixing. Am I forced to give the relative/whole URL to the trunk:

```
svn log ^/project/trunk -r124
```

or is there something easier where you shouldn't know the trunk URL at all:

`svn log -r124` (obviously not working :))

In tortoise the `r124` would be a link which you can click but I would like to do a similar fast check trough a terminal.

Comment: Try: `svn diff -c124` for a list of files and changes affected by that commit.

Comment: Not what I am really looking for although it is great that there is such an option. And you need to use `-r124` in your example so that the diff shows something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revision numbers apply to the entire repository tree, so `svn log -r124` will work as long as your current directory within the working copy is higher enough up the hierarchy to see at least one affected file.

In the case of the URL method: You do not need to use the trunk URL, you can specify a point above the trunk URL, for example:

```
svn log -r124 ^/
```